# Disprove the statement in vector spaces concerned with union of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. If $W_1, W_2$ and $W_3$ are subspaces of $V$, then disprove:

If $W_1+W_2+W_3=V$, then $$span(W_1\cup W_2) \cup span(W_2\cup W_3) \cup span(W_3\cup W_1)=V.$$

It seems that the statement is true. I have tried several examples but none of them was disproving the given inequality. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Take $V = \mathbb{R}^3$, and
$$W_1 = \mathrm{span}(1,0,0), \quad W_2 = \mathrm{span}(0,1,0), \quad W_3= \mathrm{span}(0,0,1)$$